# How to create suite dynamically in protractor for end to end testing

Tags: .net, angularjs, protractor

I have multiple scenario for e2e in config file. So i want that suite will create dynamically.

Comment: do you really expect someone to write you a tutorial on creating a test suite based on a 2 sentence question with no details and no research effort of yours outlined?

Comment: Please take a few minutes to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. you are free to edit your question any time and update it with a more reasonable and more specific question

Answer (score 0):

You can do that.

Step 1: Point your suite config option to point to a custom function

```
exports.config = {
    suite: constructSuite(),
```

Step 2: Define a custom function which will dynamically construct your suite at run-time

```
constructSuite : function constructSuite()
{
  //Logic to build the suites to be run
  var suiteToBeRun = 'smoke'
  return suiteToBeRun
}
```

In case you want the complete specs to be built at run time, then have something like this

```
buildSpecs: function buildSpecs()
{
  //Logic to build the spces to be run
  var specsToBeRun = ['File1.spec.js','File2.spec.js']
  return specsToBeRun 
}
exports.config = {
    spec: buildSpecs(),
```